# Visual Studio 2017 C++ issue with string

Tags: visual-c++

This is my code (created in Visual Studio 2017):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    string ime;
    int visina;
    double tezina;

    cout << "Unesite ime:" << endl;
    cin >> ime;
    cout << "Unesite visinu (cm):" << endl;
    cin >> visina;
    cout << "Unesite tezinu (kg):" << endl;
    cin >> tezina;

    return 0;
}
```

Afther the compiling process I got a this message:
no operator ">>" matches these operands 
This message corresponding with this line of code: `cin >> ime;`
What is wrong in this code?

Comment: #include <string>

Comment: Thank you. That is the answer.

Comment: Also you can use this method **getline(cin, ime);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a correct answer!

Comment: To a duplicate question.